# Wait until Pinia is loaded

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, pinia

Immediately launched code getting data from backend and tries to save them in Pinia.
But got an error

```
getActivePinia was called with no active Pinia. Did you forget to install pinia?
```

**Question**: Can I create a function to check if Pinia already ready or not? Is that any flag I can check?

I expected to create a function like this, to check Pinia status in a given amount of time

```js
function isPiniaReady() {
  let time = 0;
  const timeLimit = 300
  const interval = 30;

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const index = setInterval(() => {

      // success
      if (....<pinia is ready>....) {  // <- how to write this condition?
        clearInterval(index);
        return resolve(true);
      }

      // fail
      if (time >= timeLimit) {
        clearInterval(index);
        return reject(new Error('Pinia is never ready'));
      }

      time += interval;
    }, interval)
  })
}
```

Comment: Hm, `setInterval` is usually a hacky solution. Why do you need such approach overall?

Comment: @kissu Hacky, yes. I have to do an API request asap, even before Vue and Pinia are loaded. Then, once they are ready I want to save the data to Pinia. The only question here - how could I know that Pinia is ready?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't be having that error if pinia is properly initiated with .use(pinia).

But in rare cases you might need to manual set active pinia with `setActivePinia()` method: https://pinia.vuejs.org/api/modules/pinia.html#setactivepinia

Not a great example, but an example: https://stackblitz.com/edit/vitejs-vite-52kkxc?file=src/components/DoubleCount.vue

Comment: In my case `.use(createPinia())` and `app.mount()` happens after the code that uses Pinia, because that code is imported at the very top of `App.vue`.  But frankly speaking the question was – what is the way to detect is Pinia ready or not yet?